# Why (!=) Not equal to operator executes even though it is false C++

Tags: c++, c++11

The issue is that I have initialized Char variable as Q so that the LOOP does not execute but Sadly it does?! I could not find the logical flow in this operation what am I doing wrong, Why the LOOP executes even though it should not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "This program is giving you some options, each"
        " option allows you to perform actions" << endl;
    char options{'Q'};

    vector <int> numbers {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    while (options != 'Q' || options != 'q' ){
        cout << " P - Print numbers " << endl;
        cout << " A - Add a number " << endl;
        cout << " M - Display list of the numbers" << endl;
        cout << " S -  Display the smallest number " << endl;
        cout << " L -  Display the largest number" << endl;
        cout << " Q - Quit"<<endl;
        cout << " Enter your choice : " << endl;
        cin >> options;

        // Printing Numbers
        if (options =='P' || options =='p'){
            for (auto x : numbers){
                cout << x << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second condition in the if statement is true

Comment: `toupper`/`tolower` is helpful if you only want one test.

Comment: Mostly because we see insufficient effort on your part to find the answer. Also, you didn't create a [mcve] to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 6):

```
(options != 'Q' || options != 'q' )
```

As written, this is saying "as long as `options` is not `Q` *or* it is not `q`". Since the variable cannot be simultaneously `q` and `Q`, the loop will not exit.

You probably want this:

```
(options != 'Q' && options != 'q')
```

saying that the loop executes as long as `options` is not `Q` *and* it is not `q`, that is, the variable must have neither value for the loop to continue.

Comment: @ZahidulAmin You should look up Demorgan's laws

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you have || option != 'q', this is evaluating to true, and while is executing.

Comment: while (options != 'Q' && options != 'q' ) Solved it! thanks to @grenard